# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)
>   [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213271/system-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje)

I am using the following code.

```
public partial class SectionControls_SingleBanners : SectionControlBaseClass
{
    private SingleBanners _section;

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        updateViews();

        if (RssCapable(this._section.GetType()) && _section.BannersEntries.Rows.Count > 0)  {
```

So here on this code I am getting the error

```
this._section.GetType();
```

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: the above error resolved now i am facing the same issue here....protected void btnSaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DataRow row = null;
       
        if (ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new") {

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute a non-static method on a object that wasn't instantiated.

Try this:

```
private SingleBanners _section = new SingleBanners();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to set value for `_section`. You should have set it, for example, in `updateViews`.

I believe that you plan `_section` to be an instance of some subclass of `SingleBanners`, which to be determined at runtime. If the type of `_section` is clear at compile-time (like `_section = new SingleBanners()`), you would have used typeof(SingleBanners).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it means that _section is null and has not been set.  You either need

```
private SingleBanners _section = new SingleBanners(...);
```

or

```
_section = ...
```

somewhere else before you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error `Object Reference not set to an Instance of an Object...`

You declared the `object _section`, but you have not set a reference to it?

Something like:

```
private SingleBanners _section = new SingleBanners();
```

The way you've declared the private `SingleBanners _section`; the reference to the `object _section` will be null!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying

```
_section.GetType()
```

use

```
typeof(SingleBanners )
```

Comment: now this code give me the same error....protected void btnSaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        DataRow row = null;
       
        if (ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new") {

Comment: what is VewSate["Edit"]? where it is assigned? need to share some more code to find out why that error is coming. 
here it is because VewSate["Edit"] is null