# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212629/system-nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje)

look at my code

```
if (ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new") { 
}
else {
      row = _section.GetBannerEntry(ViewState["Edit"].ToString()); 
}
```

I was getting the error on this line `if (ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new")` I replaced with `if (ViewState["Edit"] != null && ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new")` it works.

Now I am getting the same error here in `else row = _section.GetBannerEntry(ViewState["Edit"].ToString());`

please help

Comment: asking what is effectively the same question over and over again is not good Stack Overflow etiquette and attracts unwanted flag attention. You've been told quite a few times that `_section` has not been initialised by other user's answers. That should be a good enough pointer to why your code is failing? You also fail to provide any code that explains how `_section` is being initialised (if at all) which isn't helping either. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your View state is null
Check for

```
if(ViewState["Edit"]!= null)
{
 if (ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ViewState["Edit"]` hasn't been set, `.ToString()` will throw an exception.

Try one of these:

- `if (ViewState["Edit"]!= null && ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new")` //best one
- `if (ViewState["Edit"] + "" == "new")`

Answer (score 0):

Well, either **ViewState** is null or **ViewState["Edit"]** is returning null...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ViewState["Edit"] != null && ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new") {
```

or if whats supposed to be in the viewstate is a string, this should work:

```
if ((string)ViewState["Edit"] == "new") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
protected void btnSaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{         
DataRow row = null;          
 if (ViewState["Edit"] != null && ViewState["Edit"].ToString() == "new") 
 {
 }
}
```

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted which you think is correct.